# Preserving arguments in function call

Tags: function, shell, scripting, arguments, ksh

I am trying to figure out how to preserve original arguments in chain of function calls.
For example consider following situation :

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

function foo1
{
        print "$#"
        print "$@"
        # Call to some other script which expect 
        # same arguments as foo3
        # ./some_ksh_script "$@"
}

function foo2
{
        print "$#"
        print "$@"
        backup_arg="$@"
        # Process arguments
        foo1 $backup_arg
}

function foo3
{
        print "$#"
        print "$@"
        backup_arg="$@"
        # Process arguments
        foo2 $backup_arg
}

foo3 "$@"
```

Output -

```
vikram@vikram-VirtualBox ~ $ ./test.sh 1 "2 3 4" 5
3
1 2 3 4 5
5
1 2 3 4 5
5
1 2 3 4 5
```

It looks like I lost original arguments while taking backup of arguments.
Script `some_ksh_script` should get 3 arguments `1`, `2 3 4`, `5` but getting 5.

Is there any way by which I can preserve original arguments ?

Comment: Why can you not call `foo2 "$@"` and `foo1 "$@"`?

Comment: If you need to preserve the array of arguments you need to use an array and not a string.

Answer (score 0):

In classic `sh`, there is only one array (set by `set` or passed as arguments and indexed with `$1`, `$2`, etc.).  If you need to manipulate the arguments, they are destroyed, but the destruction is local.  So perhaps you want something like:

```
!/bin/sh 


foo1() {
  echo foo1 passed $# args
}

foo2() {
  echo foo2 passed $# args
}

process_args() {
  func=$1
  shift
  set $*  # Flatten the arg list
  args=$*
  $func $args
}

foo3() {
  echo foo3 passed $# args
  process_args foo2 "$@"
  echo foo3 still has $# args
  process_args foo1 "$@"
}

foo3 "$@"
```

Here, you would want to call foo2 directly from foo3 with the argument `"$@"`.  the point is that `process_args` can replace whatever you are currently doing that destroys the array, and it will be replaced when that function returns and processing continues in foo3.

Comment: `set *` will flatten the argument list.  By that, I mean that if the function is called with the single argument `foo bar`, then after the call to `set *`, instead of `$1` being `foo bar`, `$1` will be `foo` and `$2` will be `bar`